# Proper module organisation for testing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project that currently looks like this:

```
src/
    proc.py
    adapter.py
    etc.
test/
    core/test_proc.py
    adapters/test_adapter.py
```

I want to run all the tests beneath test/, most of which import some modules from src. To this end, I have added src/ to my PYTHONPATH, however using 'python3 -m unittest discover -s test/' gives a cannot import name 'Proc' (from proc.py), although 'python3 -m unittest discover -s test/core/' works fine

Is this how I should be doing things (and if so, whats going wrong) or is there a better/more sensible way of organising my source and tests such that I can easily run all my tests at the top level and they themselves can import from src/?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **init**.py files to your directories/subdirectories.

```
project/
        src/
            proc.py
            adapter.py
            __init__.py
        test/
            core/
                 test_proc.py
                 __init__.py
            adapters/
                 test_adapter.py
                 __init__.py
```

Then you can discover tests from project/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html). For that you should encapsulate your project into a single directory, something like this:

```
src/
    __init__.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        proc.py
        adapter.py
        etc.
    test/
        __init__.py
        core/
            __init__.py
            test_proc.py
        adapters/
            __init__.py
            test_adapter.py
```

Then, inside `test_proc.py` you can use `from ...app.proc import something`

Answer (score 0):

'unittest discover' cannot recursively scan for test classes as of now. A patch [issue17457](https://bugs.python.org/issue17457) was added in Python 3.4 which fixed this partially, so discovery works when you explicitly specify namespace package as a target for discovery. i.e. when you run
'python3 -m unittest discover -s test/core'

But it does not recurse into any namespace packages inside namespace_pkg. So when you run
'python3 -m unittest discover -s test/' it doesn't go under all namespace packages (basically folders) in cwd.

Some PRs are underway(for example:[issue35617](https://bugs.python.org/issue35617)) for discover to do recursive scan of all directories under discovery path, but are yet to be released

So basically, for now,  you'll have to put all your tests into a single folder if you need to run all of them with one command